# merging data based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, impala

I have 2 tables in the below format.

Table 1

```
ID  Month   Measure1    Measure2    Measure3
2   1   20  15  7
4   1   40  10  15
5   1   30  20  34
7   1   50  45  54
8   1   60  30  22
9   1   25  9   12
2   2   20  15  7
5   2   25  9   12
7   2   40  10  15
9   2   30  20  34
10  2   50  45  54
11  2   60  30  22
```

Table 2

```
ID  Month   Measure4    Measure5    Measure6
2   1   40  10  15
3   1   30  20  34
5   1   50  45  54
8   1   60  30  22
9   1   30  20  34
3   2   50  45  54
7   2   60  30  22
11  2   30  20  34
```

I want to create an output table as shown below which combines the ID and month from both tables while picking the respective measure values from the 2 tables.

Output table:

```
ID  Month   Measure1    Measure2    Measure3    Measure4    Measure5    Measure6
2   1   20  15  7   40  10  15
3   1               30  20  34
4   1   40  10  15          
5   1   30  20  34  50  45  54
7   1   50  45  54          
8   1   60  30  22  60  30  22
9   1   25  9   12  30  20  34
2   2   20  15  7           
3   2               50  45  54
5   2   25  9   12          
7   2   40  10  15  60  30  22
9   2   30  20  34          
10  2   50  45  54          
11  2   60  30  22  30  20  34
```

Can you please help me with a sql query for this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `full outer join` based on `id` and `month`:

```
select 
  coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) id,
  coalesce(t1.month, t2.month) month, 
  t1.measure1, t1.measure2, t1.measure3,
  t2.measure4, t2.measure5, t2.measure6
from table1 t1 full outer join table2 t2
on t2.id = t1.id and t2.month = t1.month
```

Comment: Thanks. I had done the full outer join and it was creating separate columns for the ID and month. I was not aware of the coalesce function. Thanks again. This is exactly what I was looking for.